# Route::get function like Kohana in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Kohana have a smart routing system, I like feature when I can get url by route(Route::get('route_name',params), How implement this feature to codeigniter? Result that I need http://site.com/Sunglasses/Novus/202/ss14.05.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't support this feature (some would call it "reverse routing").

Comment: Thanks, I customize standart reverse route lib for CodeIgniter and added regexp support like Kohana do, I'm very happy with this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question properly as I haven't used Kohona, but if you just want to get the uri segment, you would use:

```
$this->uri->segment(3); //=202 in http://site.com/Sunglasses/Novus/202/ss14.05.html
```

To route a url with params you would use something like the following:

```
$route['products/(:any)/(:num)'] = "products/get_product/$1/$2";
```

so for example with this you could have a url of site.com/products/sunglasses/202 routing to the get_product() method of your products controller and then you would pick up the uri segment as above.